# Print out CSV data only if it exist in both CSV files

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have two CSV files called whatineed.csv / all.csv and I want to print out the data only when it exists in both the files.

I tried some functions but nothing seems to give me the output I need.

Thanks in Advance

```
whatineed.csv got:

Array
(
    [0] => 0424
    [1] => 9007382026
)
Array
(
    [0] => 15043
    [1] => 90073225
)
Array
(
    [0] => 15043-3
    [1] => 900735226
)
```

```
all.csv

Array
(
    [0] => 0424
    [1] => Text
    [2] => Text
    [3] => Text
    [4] => Text
    [5] => 9007382026
)
Array
(
    [0] => 456456
    [1] => Text
    [2] => Text
    [3] => Text
    [4] => Text
    [5] => 486424
)
Array
(
    [0] => 15043-3
    [1] => Text
    [2] => Text
    [3] => Text
    [4] => Text
    [5] => 900735226
)
```

I tried to use in_array

```
$sourceall = all.csv;
$sourceneed = whatineed.csv;

if (($handle1 = fopen($sourceall, "r")) !== FALSE && ($handle = fopen($sourceneed, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data1 = fgetcsv($handle1, 0, "|")) !== FALSE && ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, "|")) !== FALSE) {

if (in_array($data[$mainInfo[2]], array_column($data1, $data1[$mainInfo1[5]]))) {
            print_r($data1);
        }

// another one

       if(in_array($data[$mainInfo[0]], $data1)){
            print_r($data1);
        }

 }
}
```

This is what I want to print out

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0424
    [1] => Text
    [2] => Text
    [3] => Text
    [4] => Text
    [5] => 9007382026
)

Array
(
    [0] => 15043-3
    [1] => Text
    [2] => Text
    [3] => Text
    [4] => Text
    [5] => 900735226
)
```

because the array elements from whatineed.csv exists in all.csv

Comment: Try to compare arrays with array_diff();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Demo link**](https://3v4l.org/2TFld).

You can use some combinations of [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [array_intersect_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) as follows,

```
$temp = array_column($a1, null, 0); // considers 0 as key and null means whole array as value
$temp1 = array_column($a2, null, 0);
$temp2 = array_intersect_key($temp1, $temp); // array_intersection based on matching key
```

Create `$a1` and `$a2` from `whatineed.csv` and `all.csv` respectively. Then pass those two arrays to above snippet, it will work.

Comment: @quickSwamp when i read the CSV files then every line is a different array, how did you combaine the different arrays into one array like $a1 & $a2 in the Demo link?

Comment: In foreach loop do $a1[] = $val of your foreach loop

Comment: `$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));` Check this command from [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Comment: $a1 = 220 line
$a2 = 5000 line
in my code $temp2 is printing the **first** 220 lines not the the lines that are in $a1 and $a2

Comment: You are matching records from `$a1` and `$a2` right? in intersection of two array you will get equal or less than small array.

Comment: its workind now but only giving back only 1 record as and array

Comment: Compare my array in demo link with your and check

Comment: thanks alot it worked perfectly it was my mistake the didnt work from the start